# Can Spring Cacheable not cache when key is 0?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-redis, spring-cache

I use Spring Cache with redis. It works nice, except for the key=0 case. My annotated method looks like this:

```java
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "users")
public User getUser(int id) {
    return repo.findById(id).orElseThrow();
}
```

All users are correctly cached, except for the user with id 0. It simply is not cached and always requested. I tried this and it does not work, either:

```java
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "users", key = "{#id, 'test'}")
public User getUser(int id) {
    return repo.findById(id).orElseThrow();
}
```

Why does it not work? Is there a workaround?

**EDIT**:

Sorry, I made a mistake. There is no user with id 0. When requesting id 0, the method throws, that's why key = 0 is never cached.

However, I want to cache the response for key = 0. I rewrote my code to the following. It caches an empty optional for id = 0, which is exactly what I want:

```java
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "users")
public Optional<User> getUser(int id) {
    return repo.findById(id);
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in this method. Once stopped, in the stack trace you can see the proxy related to caching. You can look at the code and find out why it doesn't cache for 0. PS: the question doesn't seem to be related to Spring Boot or Redis.

Comment: Tried (boxed) `Integer` ? ...where `0` is not "uninitialized value" (but `null`;)

Comment: @xerx593 (boxed) `Integer` does not work, too :(

Comment: How did you configure the cache?

Comment: Everyone who commented: thank you. I need to apologise, I made a mistake. I resolved the question myself. See my edit.